# Pytorch: How to prepare 1d dataset from pandas dataframe?

Tags: pytorch, dataset

I am trying to make 1d Dataset from a pandas data frame, however, the output is weird.

I wrote the code to convert dataset from pandas dataframe: size is 8000x512,

```
# create dataset
class carte_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.df = pd.read_csv(root,index_col=0)
        self.X = torch.tensor(self.df.iloc[:,1:].values)
        self.regi_no =  self.df.iloc[:,0].values
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.regi_no)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        return self.X[idx],self.regi_no[idx]
```

Then, I confirmed the tensor size

```
dataset = carte_dataset(root)    
data,_ = dataset.__getitem__(0)
data.size()
```

I expected the size was `torch.Size([1,512])`, but the shape was `torch.Size([512])`.

Is the way to make 1d dataset from the pandas dataframe appropriate? Also, if this way is incorrect, how I should revise this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to wrap the dataset with the dataloader which will have the effect of

1. retrieving the individual element tuple pairs from the underlying dataset: `self.X[idx], self.regi_no[idx]`, shaped `(512,)` and `(1,)` respectively.
2. and collating them to form two batches of input/labels shaped `(bs, 512)` and `bs, 1)` where `bs` is the batch size.

The standard dataloader utility in PyTorch is [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader):

```
>>> dataloader = data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

Then you can iterate through the dataset via the dataloader:

```
>>> for x, y in dataloader:
...     # x shaped (1, 512), corresponds to [X[0]]
...     # y shaped (1, 1), corresponds to [regi_no[0]]
```